# React Use Form not registering value. Value is always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use react-use-form in it's most basic implementation but it's not working. It's driving me crazy as I can't see what I'm overlooking. Basically I can't get the values in the Inputs to get pass the validation. So whenever I hit Sign In, I just get "This field is required". Even if I try to watch the values with something like

```
console.log(watch("email"))
```

I still get undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my sign in component

```
const RegistrationValidationSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string({ required_error: 'This field is required' }).email('Email must be valid.'),
  password: z
    .string({ required_error: 'This field is required' })
    .min(8, 'Password is too short, should be at least 8 characters long'),
})

export const SignIn: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ onClose, redirect }) => {
  const { pathname, query } = useRouter()
  const [formIsSubmitting, setFormIsSubmitting] = React.useState(false)
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState<Error>({ name: '', message: '' })
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(RegistrationValidationSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  })

  const [getUser] = useGetCustomerUserLazyQuery()

  const onSubmit = async (formData: RegistrationFormData) => {
    const { email, password } = formData
    setFormIsSubmitting(true)
    const response = await signIn('credentials', {
      username: email,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    })
    const session = await getSession()
    if (response?.error) {
      setErrorMessage({ name: 'Error', message: 'Wrong email or password' })
      setFormIsSubmitting(false)
    }

    if (response?.ok) {
      const userId = session?.user?.userId || ''
      await getUser({ variables: { userId } })

      onClose?.()
      redirect?.()
      setFormIsSubmitting(false)
    }
  }

  const clearErrorAlert = React.useCallback(() => {
    setErrorMessage({ name: '', message: '' })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
          <div className="flex flex-col flex-wrap gap-3">
            <Input
              type={'text'}
              label={'email'}
              {...register('email')}
              placeholder={'Please enter your email address'}
              errorMessage={errors?.email?.message}

            ></Input>
            <Input
              type={'password'}
              label={'password'}
              {...register('password')}
              placeholder={'Please enter your password'}
              errorMessage={errors?.password?.message}
            ></Input>
          </div>

          <div className="mt-7 flex w-full items-center justify-between">
            <label htmlFor="consent" className="text-grey-900 block text-sm leading-4">
              No account yet?
              <Link
                href={{
                  pathname: `${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SIGNUP_URL}`,
                  query: { ...query, returnurl: pathname },
                }}
                passHref
                shallow
              >
                <ButtonComponent variant="link" style={{ width: 60 }} size="sm">
                  Sign up
                </ButtonComponent>
              </Link>
            </label>
            <ButtonComponent size="md" color="primary" type="submit" disabled={formIsSubmitting}>
              Sign in
            </ButtonComponent>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here is my Input component

```
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({
  name,
  size = 'md',
  type = 'text',
  className,
  inputClassName,
  placeholder,
  label,
  disabled,
  required = false,
  value,
  errorMessage,
  leftIcon,
  onChange,
}) => {

  return (
    <div className={clsx('relative', className && className)}>
      {label && (
        <label
          htmlFor={name}
          className="font-body mb-1 block text-xs font-medium font-medium uppercase text-gray-500"
        >
          {label}
        </label>
      )}
      <input
        type={type}
        id={name}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        required={required}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <p className='text-red-error text-sm'>{errorMessage}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```